# Definition morphism of Hopf algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras, morphism

this is my first post, so let me know if you need some more information.

I am currently studying Hopf Algebras and and exercise I have tells me to show that $f:H \rightarrow H'$ is a morphism of Hopf Algebras, given that $H, H'$ are bialgebras and $f$ is a morphism of bialgebras.

My question is, what exactly is a morphism of Hopf algebras. I can't seem to find a precise definition online. Some sources say it preserves this antipode, but I can't get my head around what this actually means.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, one can define a morphism $f:H\rightarrow H'$ of bialgebras $H$ and $H'$ over a field $k$ as a (unital) algebra and a (counital) coalgebra map. If $H$ has an antipode $S_H$ and $H'$ has an antipode $S_{H'}$, then you could say that a bialgebra morphism is a Hopf algebra morphism if it also satisfies $f\circ S_H = S_{H'}\circ f$. However it happens that this follows automatically for any bialgebra map. For the proof (see for example [Schneider's lecture notes](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/%7Eandrus/papers/Schn1.pdf)) you can argue using the uniqueness of inverses in the convolution algebra $\operatorname{Hom}(H,H')$. If $\epsilon_H:H\rightarrow k$ is the counit of $H$ and $\eta_{H'}:k\rightarrow H'$, with $\eta_{H'}(\lambda) = \lambda 1_{H'}$ is the unit of $H'$, then the identity element of $\operatorname{Hom}(H,H')$ is the map $\eta_{H'}\circ\epsilon_H$. Now the "trick" is to show that $f\circ S_H$ and $S_{H'}\circ f$ are both inverses of $f$ in $\operatorname{Hom}(H,H')$ (w.r.t. convolution product). So for all $h\in H$:
$$((f\circ S_H) * f)(h) = \sum_{(h)} f(S(h_1))f(h_2) = f\left(\sum_{(h)} S(h_1)h_2\right) = \epsilon_H(h) f(1_H) = \epsilon_H(h)1_{H'}$$
using that $f$ is an unital algebra homomorphism. Hence $(f\circ S_H)*f=\eta_{H'}\circ \epsilon_H$ shows that $f\circ S_H$ is a left inverse of $f$.
On the other hand for all $h\in H$:
$$(f* (S_{H'}\circ f))(h) = \sum_{(h)} f(h_1)S_{H'}(f(h_2)) = \sum_{(f(h))} f(h)_1 S_{H'}(f(h)_2) = \epsilon_{H'}(f(h)) = \epsilon_H(h)1_{H'}$$
using that $f$  is a counital coalgebra homomorphism. Hence $f*(S_{H'}\circ f)=\eta_{H'}\circ\epsilon_H$ shows that $S_{H'}\circ f$ is a right inverse of $f$. By the uniqueness of inverses, $f\circ S_H = S_{H'}\circ f$.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the definition is as follows, see Definition $4.2.4$ in the book [Hopf Algebras: An Introduction](https://books.google.at/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=morphisms+of+Hopf+algebras+H+and+H%27&source=bl&ots=3QiiSzCxzJ&sig=H66FoFKVdQEl57UOq77Azv21Dto&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjun8y-lNDbAhUQLlAKHTliCdAQ6AEIOTAB#v=onepage&q=morphisms%20of%20Hopf%20algebras%20H%20and%20H'&f=false) ( I found this online):

Let $H$ and $B$ two Hopf algebras. A map $f\colon H\rightarrow B$ is called a *morphism of Hopf algebras* if it is a morphism of bialgebras.